# Unable to add space in output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created a Python app to add Student and Student ID from console. It is working fine but the output is like "John01", where "John" is student name and "01" is student id. I am trying to get the result like "John 01".

Here is the function to save file:

```
def save_file(student, student_id):
    file = open("output.txt", "a")
    file.write(student + student_id + "\n")
    file.close()
```

I am new to Python and not sure how to add space between functions.

Here is my complete code:

```
students = []


def add_student(name, student_id):
    student = {"name": name, "student_id": student_id}
    students.append(student)


def save_file(student, student_id):
    file = open("output.txt", "a")
    file.write(student + student_id + "\n")
    file.close()


def user_input():
    student_name = input("Enter student name: ")
    student_id = input("Enter student id: ")
    add_student(student_name, student_id)
    save_file(student_name, student_id)
    add_more()


def add_more():
    add_request = input("Do you want to add more student information? (Y/N): ").lower().strip()
    if add_request[0] == "y":
        return user_input()
    else:
        print("Student added successfully")


user_input()
```

The code is working fine except the space issue. Here is the console output:

```
Enter student name: John
Enter student id: 01
Do you want to add more student information? (Y/N): y
Enter student name: Jane
Enter student id: 02
Do you want to add more student information? (Y/N): n
Student added successfully
```

Comment: Have you tried `file.write(student +' '+ student_id + "\n")` ?

Comment: `file.write(f"{student} {student_id}\n")`. If you're using python >= 3.6, this would work. Otherwise `file.write("{} {}\n".format(student, student_id))`

Comment: Use modern f-strings: [f-Strings: A New and Improved Way to Format Strings in Python](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python), (e.g. `file.write(f"{student} {student_id}\n")`

Comment: @bkyada Thanks!!!

Comment: @geckos Thanks!!

Comment: @Trenton_M Thanks for the suggestion, I will read about this now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use format function instead of +

```
file.write("{} {}\n".format(student, student_id))
```

Comment: This worked. I learned about format function but never thought of using it here. Still learning. Thanks a lot!!